# AWX file copy cannot find local files and files copied to local don't exist

Tags: linux, ansible

A playbook that ran perfectly on earlier versions of Awx now fails after we've upgraded AWX to 4.0.0 (with Ansible 2.8.1) in that "Copy" cannot find any local files.

When copying a file to a remote server using Copy, Ansible complains it cannot find that file. I have tried various locations, including within the virtualenv dirs such as /var/opt/rh/rh-python36/ and /opt/rh/rh-python36/root/tmp/  (rh-python36 is the env selected for this playbook, others fail much earlier)

As an experiment, I created a uniquely named file on the remote server and used remote_src to copy that file to the AWX host. AWX succeeded in doing this and completed the playbook. "Great", I thought, and then searched for the file (using mlocate: updatedb && locate testfile) as well as find /|grep testfile - and that file simply does not exist.

It's like AWX is creating a temporary file structure for the session of this playbook and them removing it, which seems to make Copy a difficult thing to use in either direction.

Can someone please shed some light?

---

```
- hosts: "all"
  become: true

- name: Copy a test file
  hosts: "all"
  tasks:
  - name: copy a test file
    copy:
      src: /tmp/testfile
      dest: /tmp/testfile
      owner: root
      group: root
      mode: '0644'
```

*Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/plugins/action/copy.py", line 464, in run
    source = self._find_needle('files', source)
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/plugins/action/**init**.py", line 1166, in _find_needle
    return self._loader.path_dwim_relative_stack(path_stack, dirname, needle)
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/parsing/dataloader.py", line 319, in path_dwim_relative_stack
    raise AnsibleFileNotFound(file_name=source, paths=[to_text(p) for p in search])
ansible.errors.AnsibleFileNotFound: Could not find or access '/tmp/testfile' on the Ansible Controller.
If you are using a module and expect the file to exist on the remote, see the remote_src option*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before running the playbook, Ansible AWX makes a copy of the files from the project path to the path  /tmp path. If your project is large, it can cause a delay when starting the job.

If your playbook uses absolute paths, problems can also occur, as the job will actually run the playbook from /tmp.

Run any playbook and check the awx_task container, the path /tmp will temporarily receive a copy of your project files

Answer (score 0):

Ah. After many hours of fighting it, I have a solution, but it doesn't feel like the right one.

I tried removing the leading / from the src, making it "tmp/testfile" and re-ran the playbook.

THIS time AWX/Ansible gave a more useful error message:

```
   ansible.errors.AnsibleFileNotFound: Could not find or access 'tmp/satestfile'
    Searched in:
        /var/lib/awx/projects/simon/files/tmp/satestfile
        /var/lib/awx/projects/simon/tmp/satestfile
        /var/lib/awx/projects/simon/files/tmp/satestfile…
```

So it is saving things on the main directory structure, but doesn't like absolute paths, which seems odd.

I then created the testfile in one of the named directories and AWX completed the task successfully.

Would still like an explanation if anyone understands this better than I.